# Error while Creating a PDF file from a data frame with persain(Farsi) columns

Tags: python, pandas, pdfkit

I wrote this code to be able to convert the data frame which has persian(Farsi) language into a PDF:

```
    import pdfkit as pdf
    df = pd.read_excel('damavand_invoice_data.xlsx')
    html_string = df.to_html(index=False, encoding='utf-8', escape=False)
    options = {
        'encoding': "UTF-8",
        'no-outline': None,
        'quiet': '',
        'enable-local-file-access': ''
    }
    css = 'body { font-family: "Arial"; }'

    # create the PDF file from the HTML file using pdfkit
    pdf.from_string(html_string, 'output.pdf', options=options, css=css)
```

but i got this error : `raise ValueError("buf is not a file name and encoding is specified.") ValueError: buf is not a file name and encoding is specified.`
and I tried all other ways which worked for English language but not for Farsi.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The error is being raised from line 2 and is unrelated to the pdf generation process (there may also be other errors). Ensure you are giving the right path of the Excel file to the `read_excel` function. This is where the error comes from https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/b3e335254f46a526ee3ce9bb757eac4011d9d1fe/pandas/io/formats/format.py#L1144